# Sharepoint 2013 Search configure for dynamic content

Tags: search, sharepoint-server, content

I have a list filled with news, and i have a page that depending on the query string I pass (list item ID), it shows the news. The thing is, when i search for this news, it retrieve the list item, and i would like to, instead of showing /lists/news/DispForm.aspx?ID=11 page, show /pages/news.aspx?ID=1 as default, and not redirecting.
I'm filling the page with c# code from the layout (in case it changes anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Display Template for the News Content Type that performs the URL rewriting.

Comment: Thank you, although i didn't follow you suggestion, i did something quite similar, I edited the Item_Default.html file, and with a few IFs I got the functionality i wanted, so +1 for pointing me on the right direction

Comment: OK, though usually you want to leave the defaults alone and create your own Display Template for specific use. Glad it helped though.